# How do I ensure that 25 users connecting to my 4 separate servers always have access to the same and shared home folders?

Tags: redhat, openldap

**Server 1, Server 2, Server 3** will connect to **Server 4** with **Ldap Client** to the **LDAP Server** and automatically connect to the **Home Folders** of **Server 4** on a user basis. In addition,

**LDAP Client** will be installed on the 4th Server where **LDAP Server** is installed and users will be connected with **ldap**.

Briefly my goal here. I want a total of 25 users of my 4 servers to connect to the **shared Home Folders** on the 4th server on a user basis when they connect from any server.

When I searched, **LDAP** and **Autofs** operations were specified.

Is there a tutorial or a step by step tutorial or video that I can do this?

**Redhat 7.9 Enterprise Linux on my 4 servers**

Thank you for support.

*The reason we want to do this. When users connect to the servers they run some simulations and always write their files to the home folder. But from time to time they need to move their files between servers and try the same files in different simulations on other servers. If there is a common home folder, no matter which server it connects from, it does not need to move files and all servers can access their home folder from any server via Ldap and each user can always access their own home folder in the same place.*

Comment: This probably belongs on superuser